# problem with super constructor when using `flutter build web`

Tags: flutter, dart, build

I want to use a subclass of Paint with an additional attribute "dashed".
As a minimal example, I just added the following lines to the standard flutter-create code:

```
class MyPaint extends Paint {
  bool dashed;
  MyPaint()
      : dashed = false,
        super();
}
```

Everything works fine if I use `flutter build linux`, but with `flutter build web` I get the following error:

```
Target dart2js failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
lib/main.dart:7:7:
Error: The non-abstract class 'MyPaint' is missing implementations for these members:
 - Paint.blendMode
 - Paint.blendMode=
 - Paint.color
 - Paint.color=
 - ...

class MyPaint extends Paint {
      ^^^^^^^
...
lib/main.dart:11:9:
Error: Superclass has no constructor named 'Paint'.
        super();
        ^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
  Command: /home/XXX/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
  /home/XXX/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/dart2js.dart.snapshot
  --platform-binaries=/home/XXX/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/kernel --invoker=flutter_tool
  -Ddart.vm.product=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true
  -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/3f3e560236539b7e2702f5ac790b2a4691b32d49/
  --native-null-assertions --no-source-maps -o
  /data/XXX/flutter/test/.dart_tool/flutter_build/232123a258e4d852bd909407e7ea3a68/app.dill
  --packages=.dart_tool/package_config.json --cfe-only
  /data/XXX/flutter/test/.dart_tool/flutter_build/232123a258e4d852bd909407e7ea3a68/main.dart
```

Is there some wrong usage of class inheritance?
Or some strange problem in dart2js which does not appear with other build targets?

I am using Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 6.5.0-25-generic, locale de_DE.UTF-8).